# Field ** in com.** required a bean of type 'com.**' that could not be found

Tags: spring

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.thejavageek.com/2017/06/16/crud-application-using-angular-4-spring-rest-web-services-spring-data-jpa/) and I'm having some trouble starting my application.

When I run `mvn spring-boot:run` in the backend folder I get the following error:

> Field movieRepository in com.movieseat.services.impl.MovieServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.movieseat.repositories.MovieRepository' that could not be found.

MovieServiceIml.java

```
package com.movieseat.services.impl;

// Java imports
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

// Spring imports
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

// Project imports
import com.movieseat.models.Movie;
import com.movieseat.services.MovieService;
import com.movieseat.repositories.MovieRepository;

@Service
public class MovieServiceImpl implements MovieService {

    @Autowired private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    @Override public List<Movie> getAllmovies() {
        List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        Iterator<Movie> iterator = movieRepository.findAll().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            movies.add(iterator.next());
        }

        return movies;
    }

}
```

MovieRepository.java

```
package com.movieseat.repositories;

// Java imports
import java.io.Serializable;

// Spring imports
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

// Project imports
import com.movieseat.models.Movie;

@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends CrudRepository<Movie, Serializable> {}
```

The following structure is used:

- com

  - movieseat

    - Application.java
    - controllers

      - MovieController.java
    - models

      - MovieModel.java
    - repositories

      - MovieRepository.java
    - services

      - impl

        - MovieServiceImpl.java
      - MovieService.java

And this is my Application.java:

```
package com.movieseat;

// Spring importss
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.movieseat.*"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.movieseat.repositories.*")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My thought is that using `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.movieseat.repositories.*")` would make all repositories accessible. But I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without `*` (wildcard),

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.movieseat.repositories")
```

Make sure you have the `@Entity` annotation on your `Movie`.

Comment: That did the trick. I also had to add `import javax.persistence.Id;` and `@id` to the model to get it work.